# Scalar product of a matrix, C++

Tags: c++, matrix

This is the first time I am using C++ and it seems like I am having some difficulties. My task has the following statement: 'If the number of rows and columns of the matrix X is the same (i.e. X is a square matrix), then find the scalar product of the elements of the main diagonal with the elements from random row K(K<=N).'

```
 #include <iostream.h>
int main(){
    int M,N,i,j;
    int X[20][20];
    do{cout<<"\n Vavedete stoinost za M:"<<endl;cin>>M;}
    while(M<2||M>20);
    do{cout<<"\n Vavedete stoinost za N:"<<endl;cin>>N;}
    while(N<2||N>20);
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {cout<<"\n Vavedete element ot X["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]="<<endl;cin>>X[i][j];}
        //usl.1.
        int k;
        if (i==j){
        cout<<"\n ELementite na koi red da se umnojat s tezi na glavniq diagonal:"<<endl;cin>>k;
        k=k-1;
        int K[20];
        for(i=0;i<M;i++)
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            int SP=1;
            for(k=0;k<M;k++)
            SP+=X[i][j]*X[k][j];
            cout<<SP<<endl;}
        return 0;}
        }
```

Comment: hmmm mind adding some meat to your question? we are not here to write your code for you..... what have you tried, which part of this homework are you blocked on, why is the code you supplied currently not working?

Comment: Actually, I am having problems with the formula for Scalar product.

Comment: Wtf is scalar product of the matrix? Do you mean determinant?

Comment: If you have problem with formula (not algorithm) you should rather do your post on Math Overflow.

Comment: Scalar product is when you multiply the first element of one vector of a matrix with the first element of another vector of a matrix, the second element of the first vector with the second element of the other, etc. and you sum them. Shortly, it looks like that: 
a1.b1 + a2.b2 + a3.b3 (where 'a' and 'b' are the elements of the two vectors)

Comment: well then good. YOu seem to know how to do for loops, you seem to know the formula..... what else do you need?

Comment: @MihaelaMincheva I still don't quite understand. According to your algorithm, isn't the result of the 'scalar multiple' of two matrixes actually a vector? You are splitting the matrix by its rows? columns? and then multiplying them separately, and the result should be a vector of scalars? Please try to clarify your algorithm and better describe what exactly should be the output given some test cases.

Comment: I have a metrix, [M][N] and a random row  K from this matrix, whose elements I have to multiply one by one with the elements of the main diagonal and then sum them up. The result should not be a vector but a number.

Comment: In summary, you want to multiply the vector that is the diagonal with a vector that is a random row.

Answer (score 0):

Several things with your algorithm:

- if `i == j`, you probably do not need to do the following loop `for(i=0;i<M;i++) for(j=0;j<M;j++){}` to calculate the final sum (see my example which is executed in O(N))
- Once you enter the row number `K`, I don't understand why you are incrementing the `K` value
- I would probably first check that `M == N` before entering all value in the matrix

Below my corresponding code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main(){
    int M,N,i,j;
    int X[20][20];

    do{cout<<"\n Vavedete stoinost za M:"<<endl;cin>>M;}
    while(M<2||M>20);

    do{cout<<"\n Vavedete stoinost za N:"<<endl;cin>>N;}
    while(N<2||N>20);

    //usl.1.
    int k;
    if (M==N)
    {
        for(i=0;i<M;i++)
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                {cout<<"\n Vavedete element ot X["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]="<<endl;cin>>X[i][j];}

        cout<<"\n ELementite na koi red da se umnojat s tezi na glavniq diagonal:"<<endl;cin>>k;
        k=k-1;

        int SP=1;
        for(i=0;i<M;i++)
        {
            SP+=X[i][i]*X[k][i];
            cout<<SP<<endl;
        }

        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MihaelaMincheva Do not hesitate to accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiply a diagonal with the elements of random row K, then why :

```
SP+=X[i][j]*X[k][j];
```

?

This just multiplies every entry with the entry that is in the mirror location (along the diagonal). 
This does not what you describe.

What you would want is the following (pseudo)

```
k= random row number
for(column: columns){
  total += X(column,column)*X(row,column)
}
```

And don't call your table 'X' ... don't.